# segmentation fault using char 2d array in c

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

I nead to create a 2d char arry looking like that:

```
----   
|..|
|..|
----
```

to do that i wrote a function numed Build_Screen looking like that

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"build.h"


void Build_Screen(char **c, int w, int k)
{
    int i=0, j=0;
    for(; i<w;i++)
    {
        j=0;
        for(; j<k;j++)
        {
            if (i==0||i==w-1)
                c[i][j]='-';
            else
            {
                if(j==0||j==k-1)
                    c[i][j]='|';
                else
                    c[i][j]='.';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when i tried to run that like that

```
char screen[5][5];
Build_Screen(screen, 5, 5);
```

it caused segmentation foult. how do i fix that?

Comment: use gdb to find an error

Comment: Looks like your array screen is not initialized when given to the Build function.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your function taking

```
char **
```

is not the same as `char[5][5]` so just change

```
void Build_Screen(char **c, int w, int k)
```

with

```
void Build_Screen(char c[5][5], int w, int k)
```

You have to pass the array, not a `pointer` to `char pointer`, you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-2d-array-to-function), it's explained.

If you don't know the size before hand, then use [malloc](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?malloc+3) this way

```
void Build_Screen(char **c, int w, int k)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i=0;i<w;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<k;j++)
        {
            if (i == 0 || i == w-1)
                c[i][j] = '-';
            else
            {
                if(j==0||j==k-1)
                    c[i][j]='|';
                else
                    c[i][j]='.';
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char **screen;
    int i, rowCount, columnCount;

    rowCount = 5;
    columnCount = 5;

    screen = malloc(rowCount * sizeof(char *));
    if (screen == NULL)
        return -1;

    for (i = 0 ; i < rowCount ; i++)
    {
        screen[i] = malloc(columnCount);
        if (screen[i] == NULL)
        {
            i -= 1;
            for( ; i >= 0 ; i--)
                free(screen[i]);
            free(screen);
            return -1;
        }
    }
    Build_Screen(screen, rowCount, columnCount);

    /* finished using it */
    for (i = 0 ; i < rowCount ; i++)
        free(screen[i]);
    free(screen);

    return 0;
}
```

notice that I am assuming that you will print the rows without using `printf` or similar functions, if you are going to, then just add a terminating `'\0'` at the end of the strings.

Comment: How do you know he prints it like that? I think what is missing is just the proper initialization of the array.

Comment: the error is in the function, not in the printing. i tried to do that and it is still a segmentation fault

Comment: and i printed it char by char so i dont nead anny \0 sing

Comment: what if i dont know what size it going to be?

Comment: Then you are going to need `malloc`.

Answer (score 1):

A char[5][5] is a 2D array and **not** a char**. It is a contiguous zone of 25 chars :

```
00 01 02 03 04 10 11 12 13 14 20 ...
```

A `char **` is a pointer *to a pointer* to a char :

```
0  -> 00 01 02 03 04
1  -> 10 11 12 13 14
2  -> 20 ...
3  -> 30 ...
4  -> 40 ...
```

You must declare it that way :

```
char ascreen[5][5];
char *screen[5];
for(i=0; i<5; i++) screen[i] = &(ascreen[i][0]);
Build_Screen(screen, 5, 5);
```

Edit: here is a full program :

```
#include<stdio.h>

void Build_Screen(char **c, int w, int k)
{
    int i=0, j=0;
    for(; i<w;i++)
    {
        j=0;
        for(; j<k;j++)
        {
            if (i==0||i==w-1)
                c[i][j]='-';
            else
            {
                if(j==0||j==k-1)
                    c[i][j]='|';
                else
                    c[i][j]='.';
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int i;
    char ascreen[5][5];
    char *screen[5];
    for(i=0; i<5; i++) screen[i] = &(ascreen[i][0]);
    Build_Screen(screen, 5, 5);
    for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
        printf("%.5s\n", screen[i]); /* or printf("%.5s\n", ascreen[i]); */
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and the output is :

```
-----
|...|
|...|
|...|
-----
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when you state :

```
char screen[5][5];
```

What is happening ? It allocates `5*5*sizeof (char)` contiguous bytes on the stack, pointed by `screen[0]`.
Thus, `screen[0][1]` is strictly equivalent to `*(screen[0] + 0*5 + 1);`

Your problem can be easily resolved by changing your function's signature to

```
void Build_Screen(char c[5][5], int w, int k);
```

I guess you want to have a function that works with any size of maps. This won't happen with genuine 2D array in C, except in C99. More details available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6936285/1794345).

Answer (score -1):

You can also access your array as a one dimensional array.
The following code was sucessfully tested locally:

```
void Build_Screen(char* c, int w, int k)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for (; i<w; i++)
    {
        j = 0;
        for (; j<k; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0 || i == w - 1)
                c[i*w+j] = '-';
            else
            {
                if (j == 0 || j == k - 1)
                    c[i*w + j] = '|';
                else
                    c[i*w + j] = '.';
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{

    char screen[5][5];
    Build_Screen((char*)screen, 5, 5);
}
```

Comment: I just wanted to say that this is othervise undefined behavior. You only got away with it because you casted to `char*`.

Comment: Since the `screen` 2d-array is allocated on stack, it will have contiguous stack memory and thus can be interpreted as a one dimensional array. If it would be dynamically allocated, this might be different. Correct me if I'm wrong. Or what else do you mean by undefined behavior?

Comment: C doesn't define casting to incompatible types. `type(*)[*]` and `type*` are not compatible. `char*` is an exception.

Comment: Indeed, that is something I didn't know and pay attention to. At least learned something out of it about C. Thank you

Comment: it doesent work for me. it sais that:
worning: assingment makes pointers from integer without a cast[enabled by default]

Answer (score -2):

As @iharob wrote, your function's signature is not working as you expect. You should use a single pointer char *c and index the array like this or something similar:

```
c[i+w*j]
```

Comment: You cant initialize it that way.